# How to explicitly annotate the return type of a TypeScript mixin factory function?

Tags: typescript, mixins, return-type

Given the example TypeScript mixin pattern described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#how-does-a-mixin-work):

```
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => {};
 
// This mixin adds a scale property, with getters and setters
// for changing it with an encapsulated private property:
 
function Scale<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Scaling extends Base {
    // Mixins may not declare private/protected properties
    // however, you can use ES2020 private fields
    _scale = 1;
 
    setScale(scale: number) {
      this._scale = scale;
    }
 
    get scale(): number {
      return this._scale;
    }
  };
}
```

How would we explicitly annotate the return type of the `Scale` function? That is, fill in the `???`:

```
function Scale<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase): ??? { 
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't  need to declare explicit return type for `Scale` function because TypeScript is smart enought to infer the return type. Hover your mouse on `Scale` and you will see that return type is

```js
{
    new (...args: any[]): Scaling;
    prototype: Scale<any>.Scaling;
} & TBase
```

Further more, if you want to use explicit return type for `Scale`, you should declare `Scaling` (the inner class) out of `Scale` function. Like this:

```js
 class Scaling extends Base {

    _scale = 1;
 
    setScale(scale: number) {
      this._scale = scale;
    }
 
    get scale(): number {
      return this._scale;
    }
  }

function Scale<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return Scaling
}
```

But then `Base` should be static.

It means that we should create `Mixin` function, just like in the [docs - Alternative Pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern):

```js
// credits goes to credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
        k: infer I
    ) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type ClassType = new (...args: any[]) => any;

function Mixin<T extends ClassType, R extends T[]>(...classRefs: [...R]):
    new (...args: any[]) => UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>> {
    return merge(class { }, ...classRefs);
}

function merge(derived: ClassType, ...classRefs: ClassType[]) {
    classRefs.forEach(classRef => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef.prototype).forEach(name => {
            // you can get rid of type casting in this way
            const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(classRef.prototype, name)
            if (name !== 'constructor' && descriptor) {
                Object.defineProperty(
                    derived.prototype,
                    name,
                    descriptor
                );
            }
        });
    });

    return derived;
}

class Foo {
    tag = 'foo'
}

class Scaling extends Mixin(Foo) {

    _scale = 1;

    setScale(scale: number) {
        this._scale = scale;
    }

    get scale(): number {
        return this._scale;
    }
}

const result = new Scaling();

result.tag // string
result.scale // number
```

You can find my article in [medium](https://captain-yossarian.medium.com/typescript-object-oriented-typings-4fd42ce14c75) and [in my blog](https://catchts.com/oop-style) step-by-step explanation.

**`UnionToIntersection`** - creates intersection of union type. Full explanation you can find in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286)

**`ClassType`** - almost the same type as your `Constructor`. It is a type of any class constructor.

**`Mixin`** - infers with help of [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) each class constructor provided in arguments and merges all their instances into one object `UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>>`.

```
`[...R][number]` - takes a union of all provided class intstances
`InstanceType<[...R][number]>>` - replace every class constructor in the union 
                                  with class instance accordingly
`UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>>` - merges all class instances
```

**`merge`** - is the same as `applyMixins` from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern)

**UPDATE**

Since, `Scaling` is defined inside a function, it is impossible to add explicit return type which includes `Scaling` because it just not exists in the scope yet.

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarian - there's certainly a fair bit to digest in your description of how to type the alternative pattern. But focussing here narrowly on the original question - is it possible to give an explicit type annotation to TypeScript for the return type of the `Scale` function? That is, one that's in the source code, rather than described by the editor tooling. I do understand that TS can often infer types (and don't necessarily want to get into a discussion about when it's best to do so). The answer may well be "no, it's not possible", which is perfectly fair - and interesting!

Comment: @MattR fair enough ) I made an update